# Java-Socket: Multiple Clients error

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

How do I handle multiple clients in Java without getting "connection refused" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649498/refactoring-good-practise-in-sockets-simple-server-cleint-swing-appl) is an older post of mine.. I hope it can help you a bit. It is a small app with a server and 3 clients. Every time a client sends a message to the server, the server sends it to the rest of the clients

Comment: Thank you very much guys.... I just cleared that problem by simply making the server "up" always henceforth it can listen multiple clients request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library [QuickServer](http://www.quickserver.org/); it will make your life much easier, since this is cookie cutter code.  [QuickServer](http://www.quickserver.org/) will take care of setting up and managing your threads.

Answer (score -1):

By creating a multithreaded server: [Google](http://www.google.de/#q=java+multithreaded+socket+server)